# Calling Bloc Event is Stopping the pageview page change Why?

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc

Here In This Go Router, I have provided the AppointmentListBloc.

```
GoRoute(
  path: DoctorListScreen.routeName,
  name: DoctorListScreen.routeName,
  builder: (context, state) {
    final phone = state.extra as String;
    return MultiBlocProvider(
      providers: [
        BlocProvider(
          create: (context) => AppointmentListBloc(getIt())
            ..add(
              const AppointmentListGet(),
            ),
        ),
        BlocProvider(
          create: (context) => SpecializationBloc(getIt())
            ..add(
              const SpecializationGet(),
            ),
        ),
        BlocProvider(
          create: (context) => DepartmentBloc(getIt())
            ..add(
              const DepartmentGet(),
            ),
        ),
      ],
      child: DoctorListScreen(
        phone: phone,
      ),
    );
  },
),
```

This is my Bloc builder Code.

```
Expanded(
        child: BlocBuilder<AppointmentListBloc, AppointmentListState>(
          builder: (context, state) {
            if (state is AppointmentListLoaded) {
              return Column(
                children: [
                  PageViewDotIndicator(
                    currentItem: selectedPage,
                    count: pageCount,
                    unselectedColor: Colors.black26,
                    selectedColor: Colors.blue,
                    duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 200),
                    boxShape: BoxShape.rectangle,
                    onItemClicked: (index) {
                      _pageController.animateToPage(
                        index,
                        duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 200),
                        curve: Curves.easeInOut,
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: PageView(
                      controller: _pageController,
                      onPageChanged: (page) {
                        setState(() {
                          selectedPage = page;
                          
                        });
                        context.read<AppointmentListBloc>().add(AppointmentListGet(start: page*10,length: (page+1)*10));
                      },
                      
                      children: List.generate(pageCount, (index) {
                        return ListView.separated(
                          physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                          shrinkWrap: true,
                          controller: _scrollController,
                          separatorBuilder: (context, index) {
                            return SizedBox(height: 20.v);
                          },
                          itemCount: state.appointmentList.length,
                          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                            var appointment = state.appointmentList[index];
                            return DoctorprofileItemWidget(
                              item: appointment,
                              onTapMakeAppointment: () {
                                context.pushNamed(
                                  BookAppointmentScreen.routeName,
                                  extra: {
                                    "phone": widget.phone,
                                    "appointment": appointment,
                                  },
                                );
                              },
                              onTapViewDetails: () {
                                context.pushNamed(
                                  DoctorDetailsScreen.routeName,
                                  extra: {
                                    "phone": widget.phone,
                                    "appointment": appointment,
                                  },
                                );
                              },
                            );
                          },
                        );
                      }),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              );
            }
            return Container();
          },
        ),
      ),
```

Then I tried to use Pageview with page view indicator. On the First page change, it is working fine getting my expected data on the page. After the first page change, it froze there. The page is not changing anymore.

Comment: Make sure that your `AppointmentListState ` state supports deep comparison. This usually is achieved using `equatable`.